# Ho exactly works JPA in Spring? Some doubts

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I am finding some doubts about some concept related to the JPA use in Spring.

Reading the training course documentation it speack about the JPA **EntityManager** interface and it say that it do the following things:

- **Manages a unit of work and persistent objects therein: the
  PersistenceContext**
- **Lifecycle often bound to a Transaction (usually containermanaged)**

So what exactly is a **unit of work** in this context?

Is it something like a **group of persistent classes** on which is definied a **JPA provider** (like **Hibernate**) and it is definied a **transactional types** (local vs. JTA)? Or what?

So I know that the **EntityManager** interface provide a bridje between the **OO model** and the **relational model** using the following method that represent some common operation on a DB:

- **persist(Object o): ** Adds the entity to the Persistence Context: **SQL: insert into table …**
- **remove(Object o): ** Removes the entity from the Persistence Context: **SQL: delete from table …**
- **find(Class entity, Object primaryKey): ** Find by primary key: **SQL: select * from table where id = ?**
- **Query createQuery(String jpqlString):** Create a JPQL query
- **flush():** Force changed entity state to be written
  to database immediately

etcetc

So now I have some dount about this interface. This is only an interface so I need a concrete implementation of it to work. I think that I have not to implement the previous method by myself but I have to use an ORM like Hibernate that provide me an implementation so I don't need to do extrawork. Is it correct?

Tnx

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, are you asking what is a unit of work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unit of Work](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow)

> A unit of work is a design pattern described by Martin Fowler as “ [maintaining] a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems. ”[PoEAA] In other words, its a series of operations we wish to carry out against the database together. Basically, it is a transaction, though fulfilling a unit of work will often span multiple physical database transactions (see Section 11.1.2, “Long conversations”). So really we are talking about a more abstract notion of a transaction. The term "business transaction" is also sometimes used in lieu of unit of work.

(Better to quote existing documentation instead of rearranging the words, I think it is pretty clear)

And you are right about `EntityManager`, it is a interface that each JPA provider implements, along with the rest of the spec (JPA itself is a collection of interfaces, not able to do anything without an implementation). Again, another fine quote of [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)

> An EntityManager instance is associated with a persistence context. A persistence context is a set of entity instances in which for any persistent entity identity there is a unique entity instance. Within the persistence context, the entity instances and their lifecycle are managed. **The EntityManager API is used to create and remove persistent entity instances, to find entities by their primary key, and to query over entities.**
>
> The set of entities that can be managed by a given EntityManager instance is defined by a persistence unit. A persistence unit defines the set of all classes that are related or grouped by the application, and which must be colocated in their mapping to a single database.